# Can I use "going to" twice in the same sentence?

Tags: future-tense

- *My best friend **is going to** get married on Saturday, and I **am going to** be the maid of honor.*

Is this sentence awkward?

Comment: What things can you *NOT* use twice in the same sentence? Is there such a thing?

Comment: @tchrist You can't use 'not' _not_ twice in a sentence. Not.

Comment: +1 for @tchrist (a trustworthy commenter). Ti Tran, no, your sentence is fine and not awkward.

Comment: Tell you this, you can use words as many times as you want. The point is not to make the sentence inunderstandable.

Comment: @SovereignSun You meant ununderstandable https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4031/what-is-a-good-replacement-for-ununderstandable

Comment: @CinCout I did, I purposely wrote "*inunderstandable*".

Comment: @SovereignSun Okay. But is that even a word?

Comment: @CinCout No, it's not a Dictionary word and everyone should avoid it unless they wish not to be understood.

Answer (score 1):

There is no restriction in the language regarding the number of times a word/phrase can be used in a sentence. All that matters is that the sentence should be grammatically correct.

So to answer your question, yes, you can use 'going to' twice in the same sentence.

Having said that, the following sounds much better:

> My best friend is getting married on Saturday, and I will be the maid of honor.